# Andengine Text Example - Type FONT is depreciated

Tags: android, text, andengine

I am trying to create a simple game. I just need to dispay text on my screen. i am using AndEngine (latest one).

None of the examples are running because it says that Font is depreciated.

Here is the example

```
    private Camera mCamera;
    private BitmapTextureAtlas mFontTexture;
    private Font mFont;

    @Override
    public void onLoadResources() {
            this.mFontTexture = new BitmapTextureAtlas(256, 256, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);

            this.mFont = new Font(this.mFontTexture, Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD), 32, true, Color.BLACK);

            this.mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTexture(this.mFontTexture);
            this.getFontManager().loadFont(this.mFont);
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

make sure you're importing the proper file for Fonts - it should be

```
import org.andengine.opengl.font.Font;
```

Comment: as stated above , the Font class from the Android SDK is depreciated , but not the one from AndEngine

Comment: Thank you. However it worked even without making any change. No idea why?